# Javascript regex to validate a phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am working to modify a script. The script contains a form to allow visitors to send an SMS to phone numbers. In the form I have a text box in which users enter the phone number of the text receiver. I am using a regex to validate the phone number to prevent spammers and make sure the user typed the correct number.

Here are the default phone numbers used in Afghanistan:

```
+93785657024
+93795657024
+93700565656
+93775657024
```

The regex validation first should make sure that +93 is used, then make sure that 78, 77, 79 or 700 (one of these) is used after +93 and finally followed by 6 digits.

Here is the Javascript code I am trying to fix. This code now works only for +937 followed by 8 digits.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test (){
  var phoneRegex = new RegExp('^937\d{8}$');
  var phoneNum = document.getElementById("receiver").value;
  if(!(phoneRegex.test(phoneNum))) {
    alert("Invalid Phone Number");
    document.getElementById("receiver").focus();
  } else {
    alert("valid");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/123559

Comment: Either `/^937\d{8}$/` **or** `new RegExp("^937\\d{8}$")`

Comment: @Bergi That would match stuff without the plus sign and combinations that are not ok like 9370, 9371, 9372, 9373, 9374, 9375, 9376...

Comment: you should consider input type tel combined with pattern attribute instead of JS validator

Comment: @dda, 9370 is invalid?  Number is present above, isn't it?  And for the plus, just add it in: `new RegExp('^\+937\d{8}$');` and looks good to me.  If 9371-9376 are invalid, then `new RegExp('^937[0789]\d{7}$');` should work.

Answer (score 2):

> The regex validation first should make sure that +93 is used, then make sure that 78, 77, 79 or 700 (one of these) is used after +93 and finally followed by 6 digits.
>
> ---
>
> This answer will not work except in the 700 case because the OP specified that all prefixes were followed by 6 digits, when in fact only 93700 is followed by 6, and the other prefixes are followed by 7 digits.

```
/^\+93(77\d|78\d|79\d|700)\d{6}$/
```

should do it.

Your original regex doesn't require a "+" at the front though.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. I also tested this with [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and says no match.

Comment: This answer will not work except in the 700 case because the OP specified that all prefixes were followed by 6 digits, when in fact only 93700 is followed by 6, and the other prefixes are followed by 7 digits. (But the regular expression does provide exactly what the OP asked for!)

Comment: I changed '/^\+93(77|78|79|700)\d{6}$/' to '/^\+93(77|78|79|70)\d{}$/' but still it says invalid number. I also removed + sign from it. Now I have this line '93(77|78|79|70)\d{7}'

Comment: @MikeSamuel Looks good to me. (P.S. I never down voted your answer. I never down vote in general, unless something is *horrifically* wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would suit your condition

Totally you need 11 digits prefixed with +.

> Therefore if 77|78|79 means followed by 7 digits or if 700, followed
>   by 6 digits.

```
var reg = /^\+93((77|78|79)\d{7}|700\d{6})$/;
console.log(reg.test('+93705657024'));
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPY7X/)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression itself:

```
var phoneRegex = new RegExp('(937(?:00\\d{6}|[789]\\d{7}))');
```

Notes:

- Since you are using `new RegExp`, I have not inserted `/` and `/` around the expression. (I am mentioning this because you commented that some of the other answers did not work at all, and I suspect that is because you may have forgotten to remove the / and / before testing them, perhaps? There seem to be minor problems with them which is why I am also answering, but the other answers should at least match some valid phone numbers if you remove the / and / that surround the regular expressions.)
- You seem to have made a mistake in counting the digits vs. the examples you gave of valid Afghanistan phone numbers. +9377, +9378, etc. are followed by 7 digits rather than 6, while only +93700 is actually followed by 6.
- My expression puts the full phone number into the temporary variable $1, which can come in handy. (I used a non-capturing group for the alternatives in the second part of the match because extra captures sometimes can be a bother when I want to do something else with the results of the match. For what your code is doing, it would work the same with or without the `?:` that my regular expression contains.)
- My expression does not anchor the match to the beginning or end of the string, because doing so would return `false` for valid numbers that had punctuation, like the `+` that you showed in your own phone numbers.
- For the same reason, I suggest that you delete non-numeric characters before checking input for a valid phone number. Right now phone numbers using parentheses or hyphens or any traditional punctuation will return `false` even though they are actually valid.
- This modification of your code would work for ensuring that valid phone numbers are recognized correctly by first removing punctuation:

  ```
  if(!(phoneRegex.test(phoneNum.replace(/\D+/g, '')))) {
  ```
- If you make this modification to your code, then it would be appropriate to add the anchoring expressions `^` and `$` around my suggested regular expression to make sure it only contained a valid phone number, not a longer number such as a credit card number.

There is a problem with the way your code checks the results from doing the regular expression test. This code will work better for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test (){
  var phoneField = document.getElementById("receiver")
  var phoneNum = phoneField.value;
  if (/^(937(?:00\d{6}|[789]\d{7}))$/.test(phoneNum.replace(/\D+/g, ''))) {
  alert('valid');
  } else {
  alert('Invalid phone number');
  phoneField.focus();
  }
}
</script>
<input id="receiver" value="+93785657024" />
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Check this number" />
```

Note: I got some of my code mixed up. Please ignore my other code (the one that was uploaded to that link, I mean). This one works.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. I removed the + sign as you suggested. 'var phoneRegex = new RegExp("93(77|78|79|70)\d{7}");' but still it returns error.

Comment: Try pasting in the entire line of code that I wrote. var phoneRegex = new RegExp('(937(?:00\d{6}|[789]\d{7}))'); (I tested it, too, and it works for me.)

Comment: I pasted the entire code and then check with this number 93700600708 so it says invalid phone number.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your code in the way it evaluates the test result, because my code is returning a match when I debug the match. Your code right now returns invalid even when I change the expression to \d{8} for example (which should obviously return valid.)

Comment: I modified your code and now it detects the phone numbers properly. http://dropoff.us/private/1372705203-1-so-answer1.html

Comment: I changed the syntax to '[0-9]' and then tested with digits. It worked. So this mean the code is okay?

Comment: @NargisAkbari My answer is now updated to a fully-working version of the code. You can ignore the link that I posted. (I accidentally pasted something wrong into the middle of it and uploaded that version accidentally.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant when I said that I did not put ^ and $ around the regular expression. You can add those, but then things like + signs will become invalid. I believe that you should add this modification first: "if(!(phoneRegex.test(phoneNum.replace(/\D+/g, '')))) {" Note: I have to go to my university now, so I will not be able to respond for a while. I will update my answer one last time before I go to implement this for you.

Comment: It is almost fixed. It says valid even If the followed digits are more than 10.

Comment: The latest version removes punctuation and ensures there are the right number of digits as well.

Comment: Thanks for everything. I limited the number of characters in text box and works perfect with your code. '<input type="text" maxlength="11" id="receiver"/> '

Comment: @NargisAkbari Thank you. I just got to my office now, and I am happy to hear that it is working for you now!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
/^\+937([789]|00)\d\d\d\d\d\d$/
```

That should do it.

> +937       All your numbers start with this
>   ([789]|00)  Either 7, 8, 9 or 00
>   \d\d\d\d\d  6 digits